# Convert an object containing more objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

This is what I am working with:

```
let object = {
  'A':{
    "a": {
        "1": "2",
        "3": "4"},
    "b": {
        "3": "4",
        "5": "6"}
    },
  'B':{
    "c": {
        "7": "8",
        "9": "10"},
    "d": {
        "11": "12",
        "13": "14"}
    }
}
```

I have been trying to compute my output result to look like this

```
result = [ 
    {"a": {"1": "2", "3": "4"}},
    {"b": {"3": "4", "5": "6"}},
    {"c": {"7": "8", "9": "10"}}
    {"d": {"11": "12", "13": "14"}}
]
```

I have tried the following which is closer but not the same as what I am looking for:
Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => {
return value
})

Comment: Shared object is not valid object

Comment: Where is the key for the first top-level object

Comment: Where are you getting the initial "object" from?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. The object had extra brackets that I mean to add. I corrected it now.

Comment: You cant use map, because you cant return an array with more entries than you originally had. I would advice to create a function using normal loop to create a new object. Do you really need a one liner response? if so i can show you another approach

Comment: I agree about map. Creating a function using normal loop sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using 2 `forEach`

```js
let object = {
  'A':{
    "a": {
        "1": "2",
        "3": "4"},
    "b": {
        "3": "4",
        "5": "6"}
    },
  'B':{
    "c": {
        "7": "8",
        "9": "10"},
    "d": {
        "11": "12",
        "13": "14"}
    }
}



let res = []
Object.values(object).forEach((value) => {
    Object.entries(value).forEach((el) => {
    res.push({[el[0]]: el[1]})
  })
})


console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome of a solution.

Comment: @mothfly_dev i thought this is the most boring solution. its like running 2 loops

Comment: a variation on this `let res = Object.values(object).flatMap(Object.entries).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))`

Comment: lol. What would an less boring solution use? I was trying to use recursion but I am too daft( also too daft to come up with a solution like you did with two forEach)

Comment: [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas). Ingenious!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let object = {'A':{"a": {"1": "2", "3": "4"},"b": {"3": "4", "5": "6"}},'B':{"c": {"7": "8", "9": "10"},"d": {"11": "12", "13": "14"}}};
let arr = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(object))).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object.values(object)
    .flatMap(a => Object.entries(a))
    .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
```

Edited to use the last `map` idea from @Thomas instead of using `Object.fromEntries`